# couchbase query returning empty answer

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

hello im trying to get query from couchbase and getting a blank answer

this is my data :

[image]
this is my data and its  keep going like that
[image]
i cant get any tagnames and im kinda lost so i would be glad to get  any help
i tryed
:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM mekorot[0] b
WHERE node.kind = 2
```

and im still getting :

```
{
 "results": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `IN` is doing what you think it should be doing. `IN` is meant for queries like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x IN ['array0','array1']`. I'm not sure why this query isn't giving you parsing errors, but try this instead:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM backetname b
WHERE b.node.kind = 2
```

Here's some screenshots showing it in action:

[image: example document]

[image: N1QL query]

Comment: got the same :{
  "results": []
}

Comment: I added some screenshots showing it in action, maybe this can shed some light on what you and I are doing differently

Comment: [{
"node": {
  "path": "data",
  "name": "data1",
  "kind": 2,
  "description": "somthing",
  "tagname": "tag1"
}]
is it changes anything?

Comment: well yes with out the [] it works so how am i looking iside it when its aroud [] ?

Comment: So is your document itself an array? Would you mind editing your question to show the full document? A screenshot even, could be helpful.

Comment: hey i edited and added screenshots is it clearer now?

Comment: Answer already has query  . SELECT b.*
FROM mekorot AS b
WHERE b.node.kind = 2. If the document it self ARRAY then flatten array with  SELECT bu.*
FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu
WHERE bu.node.kind = 2

Comment: workd!!! thank you so much! do you have any cheetsheet for that that kind of query ?

Comment: how i keep the geting more specific data

Comment: can you maybe contact me for some extra help with this data base? im willing to pay for explenations -_-

Comment: post question here will answer. If you need more interactive help check forums.couchbas.com

Comment: Also checkout https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1

Comment: i want to go deeper  in the results

Comment: i did the following :SELECT bu.states FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu
WHERE bu.node.description = "V1/V12_Voltage_0-Vmax"
and now i want to find the value at some stamp

Comment: its showing me the stamp are in : sorte_results[0].states[index].stamp

Comment: trying to do so,thing like this :
SELECT bu.states[*].`values` FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu
WHERE bu.node.description = "V1/V12_Voltage_0-Vmax" 
AND bu.node.kind =2 AND bu.states[*].stamp= 1614641220
the proble is at : bu.states[*].stamp= 1614641220

Comment: SELECT s.`values`
FROM mekorot AS b
UNNEST b AS bu
UNNEST bu.states AS s
WHERE bu.node.kind = 2 AND bu.node.description = "V1/V12_Voltage_0-Vmax"
      AND s.stamp = 1614641220;

Comment: comment doesn't allow me write big explanation. If you need to project or filter on deep nested arrays, Flatten ARRAY using UNNEST (repeat....) until desired level. If need only filter no projection then use ANY clause  (examples here https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html)

Comment: thank you very much!! 
and hopfully last question if i want to do a http query is it possible by default?

Comment: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html

Comment: i tryed doing : http://127.0.0.1:8093/query/service -d ’statement=SELECT bu.states FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu 
WHERE bu.node.kind = 2’ somthing i missed?

Comment: It should work.    curl -v -u user:password http://ipaddress:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"statement":"SELECT bu.states FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu WHERE bu.node.kind = 2"}'

Comment: and i did in the server the  CURL() Function Accesss Unrestricted

Comment: curl -v -u user:passwordhttp://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/buckets/mekorot/docs/st3 
work but the one you sned didnt

Comment: this is for port 8093:
"errors": [{"code":1040,"msg":"Error processing getting key - cause: invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"}],
"status": "fatal",

Comment: for port 8091 im getting :
"Requested resource not found."

Comment: If you need execute query through curl. curl example i gave is shell curl. It needs to use 8093, unless you post whole query it is hard tell why it gets error.  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/curl.html

Comment: curl -v -u Administrator:pass 127.0.0.1:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"statement":"SELECT bu.states FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu WHERE bu.node.kind = 2"}'
here im getting :
`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 325
< Content-Type: application/json; version=7.0.0-N1QL
< Date: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 18:44:46 GMT
<
{
"requestID": "fac6da72-10c2-4ea6-b2b0-655c63676e9e",
"errors": [{"code":1040,"msg":"Error processing getting key - cause: invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"}],`

Comment: and if i delete one space befor -d ill get :"msg":"No statement or prepared value"

Comment: Make sure Inside ones are double quotes (i.e. around statement, value}

Comment: `curl -v -u Administrator:pass127.0.0.1:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json"-d "{"statement:SELECT bu.* FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu WHERE bu.node.kind = 2"}"` this one should be ok ?

Comment: cuse im getting `curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
* Rebuilt URL to: */
* Could not resolve host: *
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: *
* Rebuilt URL to: FROM/
* Could not resolve host: FROM
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: FROM
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 8`

Comment: and question 2 can i add search by id to the query ?
like the `st3` this one works for me `SELECT * FROM mekorot WHERE LOWER(META().id)='st3'` but i want to add it to the existing query

Comment: and i tryed :curl -v -u Administrator:zxasqw12 127.0.0.1:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 
'{"statement":"SELECT bu.states FROM mekorot AS b UNNEST b AS bu WHERE bu.node.kind = 2"}'
and i got:"errors": `[{"code":1065,"msg":"Unrecognized parameter in request: 'statement:select"}]`